# How to call on async Task function from Void class?

Tags: c#

How to call on async Task function from Void class?

Let's say I got this built up like this,

I Want to call the methods in Run() in sync, but in the DoSomeStuffAsync and DoSomeStuffAsync 2
It requires await on some functions that has async awaitable functions.

My Question is, how can I in DoTask1 e.g. make the task to run sync? Like now the tasks just starts it and it doesn't wait until it finish at all.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Run();
    }

    public void Run()
    {
        DoTask1();
        DoTask2();
    }

    public void DoTask1()
    {
        var tasks = Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            await DoSomeStuffAsync();
            await DoSomeStuffAsync2();
        });

        Task.WaitAll(tasks);
    }

    public void DoTask2()
    {
        var tasks = Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            await DoSomeStuffAsync();
            await DoSomeStuffAsync2();
        });

        Task.WaitAll(tasks);
    }

    private async Task DoSomeStuffAsync(int daysBack)
    {
        try
        {                
            var data= await GetData();                
            var objj = GenerateObjects();

            await InsertToDb(objj ));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
     }

    private async Task DoSomeStuffAsync2(int daysBack)
    {
        try
        {                
            var data= await GetOtherData();                
            var objj = GenerateObjects();

            await InsertToDb(objj ));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
     }
```

Comment: Is there any way to make the `void Run()` method async?

Comment: Async void is a bad choice, generates compiler warnings, if an exception is uncaught there, your application is dead and you won’t probably have a proper call stack to debug with

Comment: The Console app static void Main() is calling on the Run() function.

Answer (score 1):

> The Console app static void Main() is calling on the Run() function.

You have a couple of options. For both of the options below, you should first make your `Run` method properly asynchronous (i.e., `async Task`).

If this is a .NET Core project, then option A is to make `Main` an `async Task` method. Then you can use [async all the way](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx).

If not, then you can have a single blocking call. I recommend that this go into your `Main` method, as such:

```
static void Main()
{
  Run().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
}
```

Comment: Hi, I did have it as async task in my main and run, but then I got told that it is wrong to have it as async Task, as it doesn't do async operations in main and run. So I tried to cut it down by removing all async Task where it run sync, and then do async task on the place where it should run async.

Comment: In order for code to run asynchronously, it must be called asynchronously. The proper way to use `async` is "async all the way".

Answer (score -2):

Async void is a bad choice, generates compiler warnings, if an exception is uncaught there, your application is dead and you won’t probably have a proper call stack to debug with. But if you want, you already have the solution just 
call directly the async task method. And wrappe it in a exception catcher

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
   Task callTask = Task.Run(() => Run());
   callTask.Wait();
}

public async Task Run()
{
    await DoSomeStuffAsync();
}
```

Comment: This code doesn't wait for Run() to complete. See [this example](https://rextester.com/QVXGA91320).

Comment: Sry my bad, in order to perform the "wait" the method should return a task